# I am looking on how to safely add database connection variables in .env file but through the blade in laravel

Tags: laravel

What I basically want to do is, to allow user to define database information through the blade file and add that in .env file any help please.

Answer (score -1):

you can't do it by using blade, you have to use a method:

```
public function updateEnv($key){
   $path = base_path('.env');
   if (file_exists($path)) {
       file_put_contents($path, str_replace(
          'APP_KEY='.env('APP_KEY'), 'APP_KEY='.$key, file_get_contents($path)
       ));
   }
}
```